# How to use both AllowGroups and AllowUsers in sshd_config?

Tags: ssh, debian

I'm trying to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on my dedicated debian7 server with both `AllowUsers` and `AllowGroups`. However I can't seem get both to work together.

---

## The Setup

- There's a user called `testuser`.
- That user is in a group called `ssh-users`:

  ```
  $ groups testuser
  testuser : testuser ssh-users
  ```
- `testuser` is trying to connect via `ssh testuser@<server_ip>` and entering their password.
- My `sshd_config` can be found here: http://pastebin.com/iZvVDFKL - I think basically the only changes I made from default was:

  - to set `PermitRootLogin no`
  - and add two users with `AllowUsers` (actual usernames differ on my server)
- `service ssh restart` is run each time after modifying `sshd_config`.

---

## The Problem

- `testuser` ***can*** connect when set with `AllowUsers`:

  ```
  AllowUsers user1 user2 testuser
  ```
- `testuser` can ***NOT*** connect when setting `AllowGroups` for its group:

  ```
  AllowUsers user1 user2
  AllowGroups ssh-users
  ```

  which results in `Permission denied, please try again.` when `testuser` enters their password in the ssh password prompt.

---

## The Question

- Does `AllowUsers` override `AllowGroups`?
- What's the best way to fix this without manually adding the username to `AllowUsers`? Ideally I'd like to be able to just add users to the `ssh-users` group in the future without having to touch `sshd_config` again.

Comment: `Ideally I'd like to be able to just add users to the ssh-users group in the future without having to touch sshd_config again.` - So why are you using AllowUsers at all?  Just put everyone in the group/groups.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, `AllowUsers` takes precedent over `AllowGroups`.  If specified, only the users that match the pattern specified in `AllowUsers` may connect to the SSHD instance.

According to `sshd_config` [manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5):

> The allow/deny directives are processed in the following order:
>   `DenyUsers`, `AllowUsers`, `DenyGroups`, and finally `AllowGroups`.

So, the solution to your problem is probably to use one or the other, possibly the group access directives if groups are your preferred way to manage users.

Comment: So would just having `AllowGroups user1 user2 ssh-users` work? I'd  prefer your confirmation before testing it since I've had it happen before where I accidentally removed my own ssh priviledges and had to go through support to fix it. How about the `Match` block? I'm asking for advice there since although I've looked at the man page, I don't have the intuition/experience to know how it would work in practice. For example with the order of processing I figured, since AllowGroups comes after AllowUsers, it would override it when processed, but my intuition was wrong there :)

Comment: If all 3 of those are groups on your system, it should work.  If user1 and user2 are just users, you can add them to ssh-users, and get by with AllowGroups ssh-users.

Comment: @Johannes when you test such thing, juste make sure you have a shell opened on the machine. Restarting sshd wont break your session, and if you cant open a new one, you can fix your mess with the existing one.

Comment: It's funny that only EL {7,8}'s `man 5 sshd_config` contain the complete processing order. All other distros (I use): Fedora 32, Arch and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS follow OpenSSH upstream docs in which only Deny before Allow is explained but not Users matches are processed before Groups. FYI.

Comment: @Jeff-InventorChromeOS In other words: If you want to allow groups, you _must not_ also allow particular users?

Comment: It doesn't takes precedence - both rules are applied. If a user is in `AllowUsers` and `AllowGroups` is present without containing one of the user's groups they will still be denied access. (If the `AllowGroups` / `AllowUsers` are present only users matching all of that criteria can login - one does not override the other one, both are applied.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a solution we have found working:

```
AllowUsers user1 user2
Match group ssh-users
    AllowUsers *
```

Comment: ... and for multiple groups, just add more blocks with ```Match group XXX \ AllowUsers *```

Answer (score 9):

Jeff's answer covers the specifics of the question as detailed, but I found this question looking to use `AllowUsers` and `AllowGroups` in a slightly different scenario. I wanted to restrict incoming connections to users in a group (ssh) coming from specific subnets.

The connection rules in [sshd_config](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5) are a filter - as each additional rule is applied, the set of acceptable users can only be reduced. `PATTERNS` in [ssh_config(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) explain the form of those rules.

Additionally, according to the `AllowUsers` section of `sshd_config`:

> If the pattern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and HOST are
>   separately checked, restricting logins to particular users from
>   particular hosts. HOST criteria may additionally contain addresses to
>   match in CIDR address/masklen format.

`AllowGroups` doesn't accept the USER@HOST form.

So, to accept users 1) in the ssh group and 2) from specific subnets/hosts:

```
AllowUsers *@192.168.1.0/24 *@*.example.com *@1.2.3.4
AllowGroups ssh
```

Comment: `AllowGroups doesn't accept the USER@HOST form. `  


Not sure what you mean by this, and is certainly not what the config file or docs say.  Allow Groups definitely does allow you to login using ssh username@example.com.

Comment: @AndrewD AllowGroups only accepts group names - e.g. you cannot do `AllowGroups ssh@example.com`. HOST is the source, where you're sshing from.

Comment: @bjacobowski AndrewD seems to be right. You can use `AllowGroups groupname@example.com` to allow users of an AD group to SSH into a machine (that is domain joined).

Comment: @stackprotector But it has not the same meaning as the `USER@HOST` form from AllowUsers. For an AD group, the `@domain` is part of the group name, completely ignored by `sshd`. It's the NSS library (winbind or other) working with AD that will do something with the domain part.

Answer (score 2):

I did a test on RedHat 8.1. It seems that it's more complicated.

```
AllowUsers user1 user2
AllowGroups ssh-users
```

If user1 and user2 is not in ssh-users group, then

1. user1 or user2 can NOT ssh login.
2. users in ssh-users group can NOT ssh login either!

The thing is if both `AllowUsers` and `AllowGroups` are used, then only the **intersection** of them is able to ssh login. It's kind of weird but actually make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In a Firewall the rules are checked in order until you find a positive match, and then the connection is allowed, in other case is denied.

In sshd_config all the rules are checked, if the origin matches two or three conditions and in one of them is NOT allowed it doesn't have access.

In this example I'm admin:

My sshd_config:

```
AllowUsers  admin
Match Address IP1, IP2, IP3, MyIP
 AllowUsers user1
 ChrootDirectory %h
```

MyIP is in the second Section, so I can't login.

I have to delete MyIp from the second section.

If I add my User in the second section I'll be restricted by ChrootDirectory

Comment: Could you please wrap your sshd_config in a code block? the formatting makes that hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [@hajimuz](https://serverfault.com/a/1038808/270331) - if both directives are defined, i.e. `AllowUsers` and `AllowGroups`, both criteria must be met by user who tries to login.
So user name must be part of `AllowUsers` and his group must be part of `AllowGroups`. This is logical `AND`, not `OR`.

Mentioned by [@Jeff-Inventor ChromeOS](https://serverfault.com/a/617087/270331) order of processing directives is no longer in man for `sshd_config` since OpenSSH 8.2:

- in OpenSSH 8.1 it was still like mentioned by [@Jeff-Inventor ChromeOS](https://serverfault.com/a/617087/270331):
  https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_1_P1/sshd_config.5#L116
- in OpenSSH 8.2 it was changed to:
  https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_2_P1/sshd_config.5#L116
  and:
  https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_2_P1/sshd_config.5#L173
  This is result of:
  https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1690
  Please notice that only documentation was changed, not processing as itself.

Finally - if one would like to mix `AllowUsers` and `AllowGroups`, option suggested by [@vimja](https://serverfault.com/a/990838/270331) works flawlessly.